# Options don't save, validation callback not executed

Tags: plugin-development, options, settings-api

I have been using settings API for my plugins for some time and it used to work well. Now it is broken and I can not figure out why. Apparently, the option validation function is not even called. Form data is properly sent and received, though. (Both figured out by `echo` resp `print_r` debugging.)

I boiled down a (hopefully) minimal yet runnable example that retains both features of what I do and structure of how I do it:

**myplugin.php**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/myplugin/
Description: Example plugin.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
Author URI: http://your.site
License: GPL2
*/
?>
<?php

require_once('Plugin.php');

class MyPlugin extends Plugin {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(array('name' => 'myplugin',
                              'prettyName' => 'My Plugin',
                              'mainFile' => __FILE__));
  }

  function activate() {
    if ( !get_option($this->name) ) {
      $options = array( 'test' => 'testwert' );
      add_option($this->name, $options);
    }
  }

  function deactivate() {}

  function options_validate($input) {
    $options = get_option($this->name);

    $options['test'] = empty($input['test']) ? $options['test'] : $input['test'];

    return $options;
  }

  function setup_settings() {
    parent::setup_settings();
    include('settings.inc.php');
  }
}

new MyPlugin();
?>
```

**Plugin.php**

```
<?php
if ( !class_exists('Plugin') ) {

abstract class Plugin {
  protected $name;
  protected $prettyName;
  protected $mainFile;
  private $hasOptions = true;
  protected $options;

  function __construct($props, $hasOptions = true) {
    $this->name = $props['name'];
    $this->prettyName = $props['prettyName'];
    $this->mainFile = $props['mainFile'];
    $this->hasOptions = $hasOptions;

    if ( $hasOptions ) {
      if ( is_admin() ) {
        // Register Options Page
        add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'admin_menu_init'));
        // Register settings
        add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'setup_settings'));
      }

      $this->options = get_option($this->name);
    }

    register_activation_hook($this->mainFile, array(&$this, 'activate'));
    register_deactivation_hook($this->mainFile, array(&$this, 'deactivate'));
  }

  function admin_menu_init() {
    add_options_page($this->prettyName.' -- Options', $this->prettyName, 'manage_options', basename($this->mainFile), array(&$this, 'options_page'));
  }

  abstract function options_validate($input);

  function setup_settings() {
    register_setting($this->name, $this->name, array(&$this, 'options_validate'));
  }

  function options_page() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2><?php echo $this->prettyName; ?> &ndash; Settings</h2>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
        <?php settings_fields($this->name); ?>
        <?php do_settings_sections($this->name); ?>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
      </form>
    </div> <?php
  }

  abstract function activate();

  abstract function deactivate();
}

}
?>
```

**settings.inc.php**

```
<?php

class MyPluginCallbacks {
  private $name = null;
  private $options = null;

  function __construct($name, $options) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->options = $options;
  }

  function general_text() {
    echo 'A simple options page demonstration';
  }

  function test() {
    echo "<input id='sanitisation' name='{$this->name}[test]' type='text' value='{$this->options['test']}'/>\n";
    echo "<br /><small>A simple test value.</small>";
  }
}

$callbacks = new MyPluginCallbacks($this->name, $this->options);

add_settings_section('general', 'General', array(&$callbacks, 'general_text'), $this->name);
add_settings_field('test', 'Test Value:', array(&$callbacks, 'test'), $this->name, 'general');

?>
```

Can be reproduced on WP 3.3 and the latest build via beta test plugin. There are no visible debug messages (WP_DEBUG is enabled).

*Edit:* Something that changed is the options page. It used to be `options.php` but that did no longer work. Now it is `options-general.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

should be

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
```

Must have overcompensated for something there.